# how to convert time format from m/dd/yy to dd-MMM-yyyy with vb.net?

Tags: asp.net, vb.net, visual-studio-2008

I have a literal on my webform. It displays date from a database as `3/26/2011` but I want it to display the date as `26-Mar-2011`

How do I do this with VB.NET?

Answer (score 4):

```
var dateString = DateTime.Parse("3/26/2011").ToString("dd-MMM-yyyy")
```

Answer (score 1):

[DateTime format strings](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/8kb3ddd4.aspx)

"d-MMM-yyyy" should do it